# Getting the error " Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server." while connecting to Docker on IntelliJ

Tags: docker, http, intellij-idea

I have installed Docker using Docker Toolbox as I am using Windows 10 Home version. But when I connect to Docker in Intellij its throwing below error.

**Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.**

How to resolve this?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85FL.jpg)

[Docker Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24WkC.jpg)

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? Please share the screenshot with Docker configuration in the IDE.

Comment: I am using Intellij version 2020.2.1

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have attached the screenshots. Please check

Comment: Did you try Docker for Windows option instead?

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the Engine API URL from `tcp://$HOST:$PORT` to `https://$HOST:$PORT`.

Comment: unable to resolve docker endpoint: Invalid bind address format