# HTTP request to HTTPS server exception webdrivermanager-java docker Jenkins

Tags: java, docker, selenium, jenkins, webdrivermanager-java

I'm trying to setup Bonigarcia webdrivermanager java with a chrome browser in a docker container on a jenkins CI server. Webdrivermanager is unable to pull the docker image from Docker Hub. I have version 5.1.0 of webdrivermanager. I get the following exception:

```
10:26:22.110 [main] INFO  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.docker.DockerService - Pulling Docker image selenoid/vnc:chrome_99.0 (this might take some time, but only the first time)
10:26:22.225 [docker-java-stream-550739255] ERROR com.github.dockerjava.api.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:237)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:26:22.225 [main] WARN  io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.docker.DockerService - Exception pulling image selenoid/vnc:chrome_99.0: Status 400: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
```

The is my webdrivermanager setup:

```
WebDriverManager
        .chromedriver()
        .browserInDocker()
        .create();
```

I already tried the following but I still get the same exception:

- activate TLS verification on the docker client
- Add the selenoid chrome image to the internal docker registry

Any ideas what could be wrong or what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is related to the configuration of your Docker engine. There are related posts, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650259/getting-the-error-status-400-client-sent-an-http-request-to-an-https-server).